# Questionaire scores correlated with 8 different surgery types

Tags: correlation, ordinal-data

Sample of about 70 people, each underwent 1 type of surgery on a certain organ.

Quality of life questionnaires were constructed, with each patient having a satisfaction score. Intervals were created.

There are 8 types of surgery on the same organ.

Which test must i apply to see if the scores correlate with the type of operation?

Are my satisfaction scores ordinal or interval?

The 8 types of surgery have proper names, must i transform each type in a number?

Comment: Not enough information. Show typical question types.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so i figured it out. When you have multiple columns of data you can apply ANOVA. I cathegorised the questionaires scores in 8 columns, each column being one of the operation types.

Comment: If you are the same person who posted the question, please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do this in the **My Account** section of our [help]).